# TextBox.Text is being disposed, even when creating the form again

Tags: c#, forms, dispose

i´ve been working on a C# PDA.
Recently I found a bug.

**Steps**

This are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Enter the form, scan some data.
2. Close the form.
3. Reopen the form.
4. When you scan data, some TextBox appear to be disposed.

**Code**

We create the Form:

```
 private void btp1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
            if(AppCore.core.pdaUser.isAuthorizedMovement(Movements.AltaPalet) == false) {
                MessageBox.Show("No estás autorizado para realizar esta operación.");
            } else {
                try{
                    //MessageBox.Show("Funcionalidad en desarrollo. Disculpe las molestias");
                    FormAltaPalet form = new FormAltaPalet(Movements.AltaPalet);
                    form.ShowDialog();
                    form.Dispose();
                }catch(WebException ex){
                    MessageBox.Show("Error técnico. " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

The first line of the Form is InitializeComponent.

```
  public FormAltaPalet(Movements movement) {

           // GC.Collect();
           // GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            InitializeComponent();
            //clear(FormStep.Step1);
           // this.FinishError(); // FIX MA 08.07.2019
            this.move = movement;
            this.tbp1_1.Focus();
            this.material = "";
            this.ean14 = "";
            context = this;

            // SCANNER
            if (AppCore.core.dispositivo_PDA ) { // BARCODE 2
                myBarcode2 = new Barcode2(Devices.SupportedDevices[0]);
                myBarcode2.Enable();
                myBarcode2.Scan();
                // Register a scan event handler to the barcode object
                myBarcode2.OnScan += new Barcode2.OnScanHandler(myBarcode_OnScan);
            }
        }
```

Here, we create the TextBoxs and labels. On the first run it works fine, it starts failing when closing and opening again.

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FormAltaPalet));
            this.pmm = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.bt_mm_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.bt_mm_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.p1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label_error_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btp1_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lbp1_6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tbp1_6 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tbp1_4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tbp1_3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tbp1_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tbp1_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lbp1_4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lbp1_3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lbp1_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lbp1_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.pbp1_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pmm.SuspendLayout();
            this.p1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
```

When we reach the method in the class, we get the current context:

```
  void myBarcode_OnScan(ScanDataCollection sd) {
            context = this;
            this.tbp1_1 = getTbl1_1();
```

But it's wrong, the Objects seems to be disposed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2yZE.jpg

EDIT: When I click the button shown in the first chunk of code, the form should be created. When I close the form it should be disposed. The code of the Dispose method is this:

```
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

It seems Initialize component works good on the second run too, but when it reaches the scan method, the TextBoxs are disposed....
**Question**

Im pretty new to C# developement, so I'm kind of lost.

My guess is that something is happening with the Dispose part.

Any way to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, remove the links and replace them with your actual code. Some of us here aren't able to click links as we are browsing from our workplace and it may be blocked! Not to mention that we can't copy-paste your code from a picture :)

Comment: Judging from the code, you are very likely disposing your controls (textboxes etc) when you close down the form. It is a little bit unclear from the screenshots if you are initiating the controls just once or if you run that function everytime you open the form.

Comment: Sorry! I updated the images to code. 
Indeed, I am disposing the form when I close it, but I create a new one!
It seems that it is the Text property that seems to be disposed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

After figuring out what was going wrong, I found out that the SCAN event was kept alive.

I added a Closing override:

```
 this.Closing += MyClosedHandler;
```

And the MyClosedHandlerEvent as follows:

```
        protected void MyClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.myBarcode2.ScanCancel();
            this.myBarcode2.Disable();
            if (myBarcode2 != null) this.myBarcode2.Dispose();
        }
```

Problem was detected with scanner event handler.

Hope this will help somebody else!